# How to display automatically generated popup for asking permission?

Tags: android

We declare our permissions in our manifest file then, when user install app from the play store a pop-up automatically generate for asking the permissions. How to display these kinds of permission ? or that pop ups are handled by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are granted automatically by the system. But for apps built for android 6 and higher, their permissions are granted on run-time, the user is asked to grant permission as they uses the app, and only dangerous permissions are asked to be granted.

Here's how, on Marshmallow and above, you can ask for a permission (Only dangerous permissions need to get the user agreement):

1. Declare your permissions in an array:

   private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS = {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
       private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST = 1337;
2. Then create method for any of your permission:

   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
       private boolean canMakeCalls(){
           return (hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE));
       }

   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   private boolean hasPermission(String perm){
       return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(perm));
   }
3. Now you can call the method on the onCreate of your activity (exemple on the Main Activity):

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ```
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
           if(!canMakeCalls()){
               requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);

           }
       }
   ```
4. Finnaly, override onRequestPermissionsResult:

   @Override
       public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

   ```
   if (requestCode == INITIAL_REQUEST) {
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                   if (canMakeCalls()) {//Do stuff}
   ```

Ofcourse there are several ways you can do that.

Comment: Yes you are correct but in some apps ask the permisssion (like accesing microphone) which is not in run time. How to do that ? Is that popups are handled by Google ?

Comment: There are few permissions which can be get by mentioning them in mainfest file, while some requires permission from user.

Comment: @Dev As I said, it depends on the API level your app support. Google made a change on how permissions are granted to apps from Marshmallow and above. On lower versions, android grants any permissions automatically, dangerous ones or non dangerous.

Comment: @jack jay indeed, those are called "dangerous permissions" as they deal with user privacy

Comment: i was looking for someone to remind me that name.Thanks @esQmo

Comment: @eqmo Permissions like accessing microphone which we are declared in manifest file (In marshmallow also). It displayed the pop up for asking permission. How ? This was handled by Google right

Comment: @Dev accessible microphone is a dangerous permission, on marshmallow and onward, you must request the user to grant that permission when the app will need access the mic, if the app support lower versions than marshmallow, the system will grant the permission. no need to display an alert or toast...

Comment: And I don't think Google handles​ this. Android does.

Comment: On lower versions than marshmallow: The PlayStore shows permissions that an app has declared on its manifest, the system grants them. On Marshmallow and above: PlayStore no more showing those permissions and the system grants those which are not labelled "dangerous" but ask the user to grant permission on dangerous ones.

Comment: Thanks friend. So you pointed that In Marshmallow and above cases we have to grant the permissions in manually like (Settings >> App >> Permission ) . Lower versions will automatically display the pop up for ask permission after installation. right ? @esQmo

Comment: Yes and no. For lower the permission is only shown before the user download your app. And displayed in the app list. No authorizations required. On Marshmallow and above, Either manually or dynamically​ within the app itself

Answer (score 0):

I wish they were handled by Google. Nah, you have to check if the permissions are granted then ask. Before, when you downloaded the app, it would automatically tell you all the permissions the app needed. Now, you ask either dynamically or at runtime. Here is an example of asking permissions in android:

```
private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        //call the code that makes use of the granted permissions
    }
}
```

Make sure you activity `extends AppCompatActivity` and `implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`.

For more check out [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) which you can use for more information to finish.

Comment: Are you sure permissions like ( accesing microphone ) that was handled by Google

Comment: Only for Marshmallow and onwards